# Methods for finding harmonic conjugate function

Tags: harmonic-functions

What are the methods for finding harmonic conjugate function? There is the Cauchy-Riemann equations but are there any other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am quoting from Ahlfors Complex Analysis, 2nd ed. p 27: Let u be the given function. Let v be the sought for function and let f=u+iv be the analytic function. Then f(z)=2u(z/2,z/(2i))-u(0,0)+constant. Then we find v easily

Comment: Thank you! If there are more methods I'll be glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant method proposed by A. Oppenheim. If
$$
u\left ( \frac{1}{2}\cdot(z+z*) ,\frac{1}{2i}\cdot(z-z*)  \right ) = \phi (z)+\psi (z*) 
$$
then
$$
v(x,y)=-i\left \{ \phi (z)-\psi(z*)+c \right \}
$$
adding these two together we get
$$
f(z) = u + iv = 2\phi (z)+c
$$

example, if:
$$
u(x,y) = e^{x}cos(y) = \frac{1}{2}e^{x}(e^{iy}+e^{-iy})=\frac{1}{2}(e^{z}+e^{z*})
$$
then
$$
f(z) =e^{z}+c
$$

To derive this method one must show:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z}+\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial z*}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = i\left (  \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z}-\frac{\partial \psi }{\partial z*}\right )
$$
and then use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.